# INSERT INTO with foreign key and data from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where the most important information is that it is auto-incremented, the rest of the fields in the database are not relevant. Before inserting the data into the table, I created a "helper" table to store the newly created IDs in this table.

I have a second table like this - also the most important information is that the ID is auto-incremented, and the other data is not relevant to this example. In this case, I have also created an auxiliary table that stores the newly created ID values from this table.

Now I would like to take the values from auxiliary table 1 and 2 and insert them into a third table that will take the smallest ID from auxiliary table 1 and the smallest ID from auxiliary table 2 and insert them as a record into this third table, for example:
Record ID of third table | Smallest ID from first table | Smallest ID from third table.

I have no idea how to build the query constructs in my case - could someone give me some advice, or ready-made (different) code to follow?

My code:

```
DECLARE @inserted1 TABLE (contact_id udt_id)
INSERT INTO t_usr_contact (contact_firstname, contact_lastname) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.contact_id INTO @inserted1(contact_id)
SELECT
'Firma',
'Temporary_value'
FROM t_sup_supplier AS sup
WHERE sup.sup_id IN (175,176) AND sup.grp_id IS null 

DECLARE @inserted2 TABLE (grp_id udt_id)
INSERT INTO t_usr_group (grp_label_en)
OUTPUT INSERTED.grp_id INTO @inserted2(grp_id)
SELECT
'Supplier contact'
FROM t_sup_supplier AS sup2
WHERE sup2.sup_id IN (175,176) AND sup2.grp_id IS null

INSERT INTO t_usr_contact_group (grp_id, contact_id)
```

I would like to go the easiest way, which is as below, but it doesnt work :/.

```
VALUES (@inserted2.grp_id, @inserted2.contact_id)
```

---

As for the data example, after the insert in the first table I will get the following records and in the auxiliary table number 1 I will get the following records:

```
**Table t_usr_contact:**
175 - Firma - Temporary_value
176 - Firma - Temporary_value
**Table @inserted1:**
175
176
**Table t_usr_group:**
201 - Supplier_contact
202 - Supplier_contact
**Table @inserted2:**
201
202
**Table t_usr_contact_group:**
201 - 175
202 - 176
```

Comment: How about listing the sample data and expected result output. Maybe my English, but this is not very clear.

Comment: I made some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I've got no idea what you're ultimately trying to do, but if you want two tables each with N rows to become one table made from the columns of the two input tables, like you've got in your example (where your table of 175,176 and your table of 201,202 shall become a table of 175|201,176|202) then you need to join them. To join them you need a key. You haven't got a key so you'll have to fake one:

```
INSERT INTO thirdtable
SELECT contact_id,grp_id
FROM 
  (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY contact_id) as FakeKey FROM @inserted1) x
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY grp_id) as FakeKey FROM @inserted2) x
  ON x.FakeKey = y.FakeKey
```

This, of course, joins the data in a very arbitrary fashion based on the order of the assigned IDs. If you want some specific order, like contact 175 exists first and has to get group 202, then you can make the query that inserts the group (eg 202) based on the input 175 output the 175 and the 202 together into a (temp) common table then split it into the detail and middleman tables after

Comment: In fact, I may have miscommunicated what to achieve.
The third table, is to have as primary key grp_id, which is to be taken from the @inserted2 table. There is no extra key there at the beginning, so the data structure in the last table should look like this: 201 - 175 - other_data.

Comment: I got something like this, but none of data going to this table:
```INSERT INTO t_usr_contact_group (grp_id, contact_id, role_code)
SELECT
ins2.grp_id,
ins1.contact_id,
'supplier_admin'
FROM
t_usr_contact_group as cg
INNER JOIN @inserted2 as ins2 on cg.grp_id = ins2.grp_id
LEFT JOIN @inserted1 as ins1 on ins1.contact_id = cg.contact_id```

Comment: Can we wind back a bit, and talk about where this data comes from originally? If it's being e.g. streamed from two files and the only correlation between them is line number, it is better to establish the in-db correlation at that point

Comment: (And if the data is already in the DB, what does it look like right now, and what do you want it to look like when you're done)